# Undo Delete Field in QGIS

Tags: attribute-table, fields-attributes

I am working on a very large point file and had deleted some field that I thought were not necessary from my attribute table. It turns out that I jumped the gun and should not have deleted the fields. Is there a way to undo the Delete Field function or to restore a previous version of the attribute table?

Comment: Certainly, by pulling and restoring your backup.

Answer (score 6):

If you have saved the changes there is no way to get your data back.
If you have deleted the fields but have not saved your data just stop editing and discard changes. Otherwise you will need to use your back up data or worse recreate it.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I got Lucky (this time) and had a backup copy saved.